# Generate test Data that follows Logistic Regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I want to test some different statistical models but would like to generate some data with known parameters.

Is there anyway I can generate data predictor variables are binary and follow the logistic probability function?

For example I would want to generate data so that if I were to run a logistic regression I would get:

Odds Ratio of x1 = 1.5

Odds Ratio of x2 = 2.0

Would I be able to have the data contain an error component as well, I.E. it doesn't simply follow the logisic function perfectly? The output I'm looking for would just be:

```
x1     x2       y
 0      0       1
 1      0       0
 1      1       0
```

Given that I know the expected outcomes I could now test different models against this known data.

Comment: Are you looking for data with those same exact odds-ratios or you're looking to generate random 1s and 0s for each column?

Comment: I'm looking to generate data where I know the odds-ratio for each predictor. I can get some random 1s and 0s with this `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100, 3)), columns=list('abz'))`, but have no way to control the associations.

Comment: Odds-ratios are pretty much conditional probabilities: `P(y=1|x1=1)` or `P(y=1|x2=1)`. So, if you can use the information you got to deduce `P(x1=1)` and `P(x2=1)`, then I think you can utilize `numpy.random.choice` and those calculated probability values.